# Comparing sample mean vs random assortments in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Given df

```
            A         B         C
Date            
2010-01-17  -0.9304   3.7477    0.0000
2010-01-24  -3.6348   1.5733   -3.6348
2010-01-31  -1.8950   0.4957   -1.8950
2010-02-07  -0.6990  -0.1480   -0.6990
2010-02-14   1.4635  -3.4206    1.4635
```

I would like to compare the mean of df['C'] with 10.000 random series created from picking 1 element of df['A'] OR from df['B'], for EACH date, to see where the mean ranks (1 if is the highest, 0.95 if is higher than 9500 randoms, etc).

I had an old formula written but I can't put it together again, maybe this helps

```
def mean_diff(d):
    result = {}
    for k, (l, t) in d.iteritems():
        m = np.mean(t)
        len_ = len(t)
        result[k] = np.mean([m > np.mean(npr.choice(l, len_, True))
                            for _ in range(10000)])
    return result
```

Thanks

** 10000 because the original data has a lot more than 5 rows.

UPDATE:

Well, in order to solve this problem, I have to start solving a smaller problem. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35566771/random-selection-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there's a shortcut:

Since we have equal number of elements in both columns A, B. We could put them in a list and take the 10000 random samples from that list and compare them with the mean of C

```
sample = df['C'].values
a = df['A'].values
b = df['B'].values
population = np.concatenate((a,b), axis=0)

def mean_diff(s, p):
    m = np.mean(s)
    len_ = len(s)
    result = np.mean([m > np.mean(npr.choice(p, len_, True))
                            for _ in range(10000)])
    return result

mean_diff(sample, population)
```