# Random selection in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, random

I'm trying to solve [this more complicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35559193/comparing-sample-mean-vs-random-assortments-in-python). Here's a smaller problem:

Given df

```
a    b
1    2
5    0
5    9
3    6
1    8
```

How can I create a column C that is a random selection between the two elements of df['a'] and df['b'] of the same row?

So, given this dummy df, the random operator would choose from the pair (1, 2) for row #1, from (5, 0) for row #2...etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random

n = 2  # target row number
random.sample(df.iloc[n, :2], 1)  # Pick one number from this row.
```

For the whole dataframe:

```
>>> df.loc[:, ['a', 'b']].apply(random.sample, args=(1,), axis=1)
0    [1]
1    [5]
2    [9]
3    [3]
4    [8]
dtype: object
```

Cleaning it up to extract the single values:

```
>>> pd.Series([i[0] for i in df.loc[:, ['a', 'b']].apply(random.sample, args=(1,), axis=1)], index=df.index)
0    1
1    5
2    9
3    3
4    8
dtype: int64
```

Or taking advantage that column 'a' is indexed at zero (False) and column 'b' is indexed at 1 (True):

```
>>> [df.iat[i, j] for i, j in enumerate(1 * (np.random.rand(len(df)) < .5))]
[1, 5, 5, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to use a separate `random` module:

```
s = """a    b
1    2
5    0
5    9
3    6
1    8
"""

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(s),sep='\s+',engine='python')
df.apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=1).iloc[0],axis=1)
#output:
0    1
1    5
2    9
3    6
4    1
dtype: int64
```